# How to load 800 GB of data into a hive table using Spark?

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hadoop-yarn

We have a big time series of three-component magnetic field (north, east, down) measured at many different stations.

We want to analyze this data using Spark with Python. We are using Spark 1.6.1 and Yarn as cluster manager. I am running a spark-submit job in a yarn `client` deploy mode.

In my code, I am reading 90-93 files [30-31 for each month * 3 (for North,East and Down)] using `sc.binaryFiles` for each month and doing a `combineByKey` on 90 files to combine it for each day to finally get 30 days for all north, east and down in a `DataFrame`. Repeating this for all months and all stations and all years to load it in a hive table on HDFS.

I am trying to load 800 GB (10 years) of data (each date is a `npy` file of 17 MB) to a Hive table for our data analysis. We have a cluster of 4 nodes with 122 GB of memory, 44 vCores. I am using 465 GB memory out of 488 GB available. I am using `pyspark` code for reading the `npy` files as `sc.binaryFiles`, 90 files for each iteration. I am giving the spark-submit with the following parameters

```
--num-executors 16 --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 26G --executor-cores 10 \
--conf "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=2048" \
--conf "spark.shuffle.memory.fraction=0.8" \
--conf "spark.storage.memoryFraction=0.2" \
--conf "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2600" \
--conf "spark.yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb=123880" \
--conf "spark.yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores=43"
```

But I am always getting the following error after around 130 iterations.

```
org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:323)
```

Also, I am submitting a new job for each year.

Even though I am processing just 90 files per iteration why do I get this error? Is it possible to iterate through all years, all stations and all months in a job? My iteration logic processes all years, stations and months but not able to run it in Spark without failure.

Kindly advise me on how to make spark run my job successfully.

Comment: Reason is you are doing lot of shuffling. Pls check my answer hope that helps

Comment: @philantrovert: Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @Ram Ghadiyaram: Thanks for the answer. I will try with spark.sql.shuffle.partitions < 2000 and will let you know about the job performance.

Comment: also... see [ShuffleBlockFetcherIteratorSuite.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/storage/ShuffleBlockFetcherIteratorSuite.scala) test case for better understanding

Comment: Sure. Thanks. To add more to my question, I am already processing the data for each year separately. But the data is not equal for all years. If an year has around 100 gigs of data, then my job wouldn't complete without that shuffle exception whereas if an year has less data, it completes.